# how to Upgrade apache httd and openssh to the latest version on endian firewall(Endian Firewall Community is a "turn-key" linux security distribution)?

Tags: linux, security, firewall

how to Upgrade apache httd and openssh to the latest version on endian firewall(Endian Firewall Community is a "turn-key" linux security distribution)?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're going to want to look at just updating the entire Endian environment.

If you start changing parts of a "turn-key" solution, you're likely going break something - and not because you're not smart, but because there are piddling little details and dependencies you don't know about.

Endian Community documentation - http://www.endian.com/en/support/documentation/